# Not able to Navigate to root viewcontroller(Home) in swift

Tags: swift, uinavigationcontroller, root

I have added NavigationControllerScene to ViewController and made it initial viewcontroller in storyboard

**code:** if I use below code tap on **testBtn** not able to go to ViewController1. why? i want show ViewController with sidemenu and bottom tabbar thats why i have written code like this. added added same code in Appdelegate and Scenedelagate as well

**Why not able to Navigate from ViewController to ViewController1?**

this is my info.plist

[image]

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    setUpNavigationBar(with: "Viewcontroller", isBackNeed: false)
}


@IBAction func testBtn(_ sender: UIButton){
    // added same code in Appdelegate and scenedelagete as well
    let home = Helper.getVcObject(vcName: .ViewController1, StoryBoardName: .Main) as! ViewController1
    let menu = Helper.getVcObject(vcName: .MenuViewController, StoryBoardName: .Main) as! MenuViewController
    let nav = MainNavigationController(rootViewController: home)
    let sideMenu = SideMenuController(contentViewController: nav, menuViewController: menu)
    Helper.replaceRootView(for: sideMenu)
    
}
}
```

**and some of my custom methods:**

```
let keyWindow = UIApplication.shared.connectedScenes
.filter({$0.activationState == .foregroundActive})
.compactMap({$0 as? UIWindowScene})
.first?.windows
.filter({$0.isKeyWindow}).first

enum StoryBoardNameCase: String {
case Main = "Main"

}

enum VCNameCase: String {
case MenuViewController = "MenuViewController"
case ViewController1 = "ViewController1"
}

class Helper {

static func getVcObject(vcName:VCNameCase, StoryBoardName:StoryBoardNameCase) -> UIViewController{
    
    let storyBoard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: StoryBoardName.rawValue, bundle: nil)
    let vc = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: vcName.rawValue)
    
    return vc
}

static func replaceRootView(for rootViewController: UIViewController, animated: Bool = true, completion: (() -> Void)? = nil) {
    if animated {
        UIView.transition(with: keyWindow ?? UIWindow(), duration: 0.5, options: .transitionCrossDissolve, animations: {
            let oldState: Bool = UIView.areAnimationsEnabled
            UIView.setAnimationsEnabled(false)
            keyWindow?.rootViewController = rootViewController
            keyWindow?.makeKeyAndVisible()
            UIView.setAnimationsEnabled(oldState)
        }, completion: { (finished: Bool) -> () in
            completion?()
        })
    } else {
        keyWindow?.rootViewController = rootViewController
        keyWindow?.makeKeyAndVisible()
    }
}
```

**EDIT: AppDelegate: code** added same code in SceneDelegate as well

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    
    let home = Helper.getVcObject(vcName: .ViewController1, StoryBoardName: .Main) as! ViewController1
    let menu = Helper.getVcObject(vcName: .MenuViewController, StoryBoardName: .Main) as! MenuViewController
    let nav = MainNavigationController(rootViewController: home)
    let sideMenu = SideMenuController(contentViewController: nav, menuViewController: menu)
    Helper.replaceRootView(for: sideMenu)
    
    SideMenuController.preferences.basic.menuWidth = UIScreen.main.bounds.width * 0.8
    
    return true
}
```

SceneDelegate code:

```
 func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) 
{
    // Use this method to optionally configure and attach the UIWindow `window` to the provided UIWindowScene `scene`.
    // If using a storyboard, the `window` property will automatically be initialized and attached to the scene.
    // This delegate does not imply the connecting scene or session are new (see `application:configurationForConnectingSceneSession` instead).
        
    let home = Helper.getVcObject(vcName: .ViewController1, StoryBoardName: .Main) as! ViewController1
    let menu = Helper.getVcObject(vcName: .MenuViewController, StoryBoardName: .Main) as! MenuViewController
    let nav = MainNavigationController(rootViewController: home)
    let sideMenu = SideMenuController(contentViewController: nav, menuViewController: menu)
    Helper.replaceRootView(for: sideMenu)
    
    SideMenuController.preferences.basic.menuWidth = UIScreen.main.bounds.width * 0.8
    
}
```

Comment: can you share the UI that you expect?

Comment: and also you want to navigate(push) to viewController1 or set the rootviewController to viewController1?

Comment: if your viewController is in a UINavigationController you can push to every ViewController that you want, but if the ViewController is lonely the RootViewController push event doesn't work(because there isn't any navigation controller). it means your root viewcontroller should set a navigationcontroller that has a rootviewcontroller with ViewController. that's it.

Comment: could you share your appdelegate or scenedelegate code section that your are setting the rootviewcontroller?

Comment: @MaziarSaadatfar, added AppDelegate and SceneDelegate code, yes i want Viewcontroller1 to be rootviewcontroller

Comment: @MaziarSaadatfar, for eg imagine here `testBtn` is Log in button. once login i need home(viewcontroller1) to rootviewcontroller

Comment: can you check it: let scene = UIApplication.shared.connectedScenes.first , if let sceneDelegate: SceneDelegate = (scene?.delegate as? SceneDelegate) { sceneDelegate.initYourRootViewController } , initYourRootViewController is function on sceneDelegate

Comment: in your scenedelegate:  
 func initYourRootViewController(config: MainTabbarConfig) {
        window?.rootViewController =  youRootvC
        window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
    }

Comment: you should use one of them AppDelegate or SceneDelegate, if in info.plist(Application Scene Manifest) you use from scene delegate you should define it in scenedelegate.

Comment: if you use from appdelegate, you should use: "let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate "and the function I defined should be defined on appdelegate(initYourRootViewController).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255379/discussion-between-swift-and-maziar-saadatfar).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are using in info plist from **"Application Scene Manifest"** you should define your root view controller in SceneDelegate:

[image]

So you define your LoginViewController As rootViewController on SceneDelegate

```
class SceneDelegate: UIResponder, UIWindowSceneDelegate {
    var window: UIWindow?
    func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {
        guard let scene = (scene as? UIWindowScene) else { return }
        self.window = UIWindow(windowScene: scene)
        window?.rootViewController = yourLoginVC
        window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
    }

    func initNewMainVC(rootVC: UIViewController) {
        window?.rootViewController = rootVC
        window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
    }
}
```

in your class:

```
static func replaceRootView(for rootViewController: UIViewController, animated: Bool = true, completion: (() -> Void)? = nil) {
    let scene = UIApplication.shared.connectedScenes.first
        if let sceneDelegate: SceneDelegate = (scene?.delegate as? SceneDelegate) {
            sceneDelegate.initNewMainVC(rootVC: rootViewController)
        }
}
```

but if you use from AppDelegate means you don't use from SceneDelegate and don't have **"Application Scene Manifest"** in the **info.plist**:

you should define all of that defined on SceneDelegate to Appdelegate and set it on appdelegate:

```
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {
    var window: UIWindow?
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
        self.window?.rootViewController = yourLoginVC
        self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
        return true
    }


    func initNewMainVC(rootVC: UIViewController) {
        window?.rootViewController = rootVC
        window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
    }
}
```

in your class:

```
static func replaceRootView(for rootViewController: UIViewController, animated: Bool = true, completion: (() -> Void)? = nil) {
        if let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate {
            appDelegate.initNewMainVC(rootVC: rootViewController)
        }
}
```

you should use One of them SceneDelegate or AppDelegate